# Twilio - record and hangup after silence

Tags: twilio, twilio-twiml

I am executing an outbound call, and specify the record=true.
in this call, there is only one verb which is the  audio.
Everything works good.

The call is hangup-ed just when the Audio finish.
But, I want to give a chance to the user to speak and record him until silence after the Audio finish, and then to hangup. Of course I need the record the whole call.

So I can use `<Pause>`, but it's very strict, for X time and not until silence from the other side of the call.

I can use `<Record>` verb after the `<Play>` verb, but it adds another Record in addition to the whole-call record.

Any idea?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

You could use [`<Gather>` with `speechTimeout`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/gather#speechtimeout) set to `auto`. You would be doing unnecessary voice transcription (though that might be useful to you), but it should allow you to listen until the user stops talking.

Alternatively, you could just `<Record>` the user's part, since you know you are sending them the audio to listen to.